# What is the best way to create multiple Magento product pages for the same product with slightly differing attributes?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a product, a Spacebar (not really a spacebar, it's an example). It works in many different keyboard models and the powers that be would like a separate product page for each keyboard model, e.g. www.example.com/model-x-spacebar, www.example.com/model-y-spacebar. These pages would all have slightly differing text (according to which model the user is viewing) but in the end the user is going to get the same spacebar. Basically, the goal is to make it appear to the user as if Model X Spacebar and Model Y Spacebar are unique products, while having the workers think it's a single product. Can I do such a thing? How would I manage inventory levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is to create a grouped product for every text variation, and include the same 'Spacebar' as the product in each. This will only work if the 'Spacebar' is a simple product. This will let you only have the one inventory level of the simple product.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll try this. I really didn't want to manage the inventory levels on my own